# combining 2 regex into one

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that will:
- check the first 2 characters equal 04
- check the length is 10 and contains numbers

I have this, and tried numberous things but couldn't find how to combine the 2 in one using a 'and' or if I have the first check even right...

```
pattern = "(04{1,1})/([0-9]{10,10})"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following

```
/^04[0-9]{8}$/
```

Comment: hmm it is still saying "Please match the format requested" - im using chrome

Comment: can you provide some sample text?